# Alternative for ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")

Tags: javascript, activex, activexobject

I am working on javascript project where i want to run shell commands through java script code  , I am able to do it with active x objects using "ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")" successfully  , how can i do it without acitive x ?

I am doing opertation something similar to this

```html
//inside some function
var abc=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")

HKEY_Key="header";
//abc.RegWrite(HKEY_Root+HKEY_Path+HKEY_Key,"&w");
HKEY_Key="footer";
//abc.RegWrite(HKEY_Root+HKEY_Path+HKEY_Key," &b Printed on &d &t &b Page &p of &P");
```

Comment: `WScript.Shell` is capable to read and write to local disks and perform many other OS operations, that is not possible via a web page. You need to create an add-on or create ex. Electron app, or use some other local server system.

Comment: Thank you. I am using angular 1 for my application can there be any alternative considering the platform? and can you also please elaborate on local server system that would be helpful

Comment: [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) uses [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) as a local server. You can also install and run many other servers locally (you can search for WAPP, WAMP for further information). Then you'd need a browser extension (add-on) to make the web page to interact with the local server. Accessing the registry of a local machine via a web page is just not possible. If you can access ActiveX in Internet Explorer via a web page, you've heavily misconfigured your browser, and taking a huge security risk.